# Ignore response errors VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, post, request, httpwebrequest

I have a problem with getting response, when I am getting response like 400 error or 403 error, poping up unexpected event error.
My question is how to ignore these errors?

Here is the code:

```
        Dim postData As String = "{""agent"": {""name"": ""Minecraft"",""version"": 1},""username"": " + TextBox1.Text + ",""password"": " + TextBox2.Text + ",""clientToken"": ""client identifier""}"
    Dim tempCookies As New CookieContainer
    Dim encoding As New UTF8Encoding
    Dim byteData As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postData)

    Dim postReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate"), HttpWebRequest)
    postReq.Method = "POST"
    postReq.KeepAlive = True
    postReq.CookieContainer = tempCookies
    postReq.ContentType = "application/json"
    postReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/4.0 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
    postReq.ContentLength = byteData.Length
    postReq.UseDefaultCredentials = True
    postReq.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
    postReq.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
    Dim postreqstream As Stream = postReq.GetRequestStream()
    postreqstream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
    postreqstream.Close()
    Dim postresponse As HttpWebResponse


    postresponse = DirectCast(postReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    tempCookies.Add(postresponse.Cookies)
    logincookie = tempCookies
    Dim postreqreader As New StreamReader(postresponse.GetResponseStream())
    Dim thepage As String = postreqreader.ReadToEnd


    RichTextBox1.Text = thepage
    If thepage.Contains(":true") Then
        MsgBox("Valid")
    End If
    If thepage.Contains("ForbiddenOperationException") Then
        MsgBox("Not Valid")
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Around each statement for which you wish to ignore exceptions, place a try/catch where the 'catch' is empty:

```
Try
    ... single statement
Catch
   //empty
End Try
```

However, *are you sure* you want to just ignore exceptions?

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub test()   
 On Error GoTo ErrHand
    'Code here

    Exit Sub
    ErrHand:
Msgbox("You got the error 91")
    If Err.Number = 91 Then Goto Errhand
    End Sub
```

Comment: Either option for ignoring errors smells bad, but you should be able to do this better with structured exception handling.

Comment: And how I can do it with structure exception handling?

Comment: if you just want ignore just use instead" On Error Resume Next "

Comment: 'Try/Catch' for each statement for which you want to ignore exceptions, and the 'Catch' is empty.

Comment: I assume the infinite loop on error 91 was unintentional?